# My GCP VM server works with external IP address but not from domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, virtual-machine

I am grappling with a strange issue. I recently moved my hosting from godaddy to GCP (due to some domain mitigation at godaddy which is another story). I copied over the required files and verified that my external IP address for the VM works fine when accessed from internet.

Then I updated the A record and CNAME records in my godaddy DNS to this external IP address. I verified that they have been propagated. But still i am getting Err_Connection_Refused.

I suspected some issue in DNS.. so i moved the DNS to google managed DNS and updated the name servers at my hosting (godaddy). But still the website is not opening.

When I do `netstat -a` from my instance, i see the following:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

My machine OS is Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2

GCP VPC firewall port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS are enabled as seen below:

[image: Google cloud firewall settings]

Also Compute Engine Network tags http-server and https-server are checked (enabled)
[image]

Netstat output on VM

[image]

My external IP works  http://
but the website doesnt  http://.app

A records, NS all look fine.

Comment: Edit your question with details. 1) Some operating systems include an OS firewall. What is the OS version and is the firewall enabled and which ports are enabled? 2) Google Cloud VPC firewall requires enabling port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. Which ports are enabled in the VPC firewall? 3) You can optionally add the Compute Engine Network tags **http-server** and **https-server** to allow HTTP and HTTPS. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances

Comment: Thanks John. I have added more details. Google cloud VPC firewall looks fine and also the  Network tags are checked

Comment: Striking thing here is that if i access my external IP via http://<vm external IP> then it works fine. But my domain is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research I think I have found the problem. My domain is a .app TLD which among a few other TLDs is a HSTS TLD. It means by default the https protocol is requested for such domains. We need to have the SSL enabled and virtual host configured on port 443. It should solve the problem. phew!